# passing customlist data to another activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, android-actionbar

I know how to pass data from one activity to another. But what I want here is, I have custom list in which each row is having 3 columns and 3 rows. I have set up QuickActions to provide more actions related to each list item. When user clicks on a list item, QuickAction popup is appeared showing 4 actions for each item. List is generated from the response taken from server.

Here's a snapshot - 
[image: QucikAction bar after clicking on a list item]

Now when user clicks on **Add** , I want to pass suppose `user_id`. Similarly when user clicks on **Accept** I want pass `post_id` and likewise. `user_id`, `post_id` are not shown in list but they are already taken from server.

How can I do this ?

code from where I want to start new activity -

```
mQuickAction.setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener()  {
public void onItemClick(QuickAction quickAction, int pos,int actionId) {
    ActionItem actionItem = quickAction.getActionItem(pos);
   if (actionId == ID_ADD) { 
       // if Add item selected , pick up data from current list item and start new  Intent. I can't figure out how can I get data for current item.
    } else {

        }

 }
});
```

Comment: Add them to the Intent object, which you are using to call other activity.

Comment: yes, I can do that. But how can get the values from list item to pass to other activity.

Comment: you have Array for list and list have onlistitem click method that returns you position and get your all id from your array position...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **setTag()** at the time of populating list view item's, write cod in getView() of custom adaptor. when you click on item in list view use **getTag() property**. and then pass through intents.